How to increase my bike power (not enough space for bigger chainring)
I have a bike with full shimano deore M5100 1x11s. I want to increase the power of it. I tryed to increase the chainring size but my frame accept max 34t (not enough space for bigger). I would like to increase to 38t or 40t but I can’t find a solution for that. I am thinking about replacing my crankset FC-M5100 for a wider one so i can use bigger chainring. Will it solve my problem ? What crankset should i buy? Is there another solution for my problem?


Bigger chainrings don't make you more powerful or faster, unless you're already strong enough so spin out - meaning you hit 100+ rpm or even faster when you have the chain on the smallest cog in the rear.  There's a good reason the strongest pro riders pretty much use the same chainring sizes as mere mortals.  In fact, one of the major reasons 50t chainrings are now popular on road bikes instead of the "ME BIG! ME STRONG!" 53-tooth chainrings that used to be de riguer is because Alberto Contador used a 50t chainring.  If Alberto Contador doesn't need larger chainrings...

The Deore M5100 line has a 2x crank, so if you swapped that on you could probably fit a larger chainring on the outer position.  Don't know what that would do to your chain line, though.

@AndrewHenle Everyone is racing on 52+ tooth rings except in the mountains. But have you considered a 34t single ring for your own bike? I'm sure you'd find it revelatory.

@Noise And that contradicts my comment how? But have you considered a 34t single ring for your own bike? I'm sure you'd find it revelatory.  How about you post a training ride where YOU hit 160 RPM? Or ride for 90 min at 95+ rpm and stop commenting from ignorance?  "I need a bigger chainring to go faster" is wrong unless you're spinning out - and the OP almost certainly isn't.  And if you own a bike shop and have "experience ... with high end road bikes", you doggone well know that.

It looks to be a mountain bike, optimized for chain retention. Going fast for a distance isn't its designed use and trying to change that may be ultimately unsatisfactory.

My city is very flat, not a lot of mountains so I tried 34t but is not enough because my cassette is 11x51 not 10x51.  I will try what @DavidW suggested, nice idea

@Noise The real question is why do you have so much emotionally invested in bigger chainrings to the point of getting insulting?  ME RIDE BIG CHAINRING! doesn't make you any faster.  Anyone who thinks so isn't fast anyway and/or knows nothing about how to actually get fast.

It's efficiency @AndrewHenle . Riding a small ring, using the 11/12/13 sprockets gives poor drivetrain efficiency and increased wear. For all your high RPM riding, you are not producing much average power or high speed, so what is the advantage for you?

@Noise For all your high RPM riding, you are not producing much average power or high speed, so what is the advantage for you?  U funny  "Avg Watts 396 watts"  You are totes adorbs.  Now go back to spewing nonsense about things you know nothing about.

@AndrewHenle That's an 11 mile flat ride Andrew! You went out for a blast and your cadence was not particularly high for that power output. You are really proving my point here.

@Noise 3 hours, 270W - and note the max power there - 1700+W.  I've hit over 2000W. And USA Cycling sanctioned race results  Notice there's a podium in there.  What have you got besides your ME BIG! ME EGO SAY RIDE BIG CHAIN RING! nonsense?  I have actual experience that includes USA  Cycling sanctioned races.  If you've never pinned on a number, you don't know what fast really means.

@AndrewHenle I'm looking at the stats of a good cyclist with alot of potential (you) being wasted on twiddling your legs too fast. I honestly think consulting with a different coach and trying a different training philosophy would unlock alot of performance for you.

Your wording is imprecise. A bigger chainring will give you less torque and a higher gear ratio. Power will not change, as it is limited by the rider, or the motor in case of an e-bike.

@Noise  Now you're getting pathetic.  Alpe d'Huez - Tour de France  KOM: Sepp Kuss, 39:54, 371W  So my 396W for 28 min is what, again?  You labelled that "You went out for a blast..." in utter ignorance, and now you're being condescending? "I honestly think consulting with a different coach and trying a different training philosophy would unlock alot of performance for you."?!!!?? Seriously?  I posted power levels right about what the top pros put out. Again:  You don't know what you're talking about.

@AndrewHenle and Noise would you mind discussing somewhere else (Chat?) the question on who has the proven palmares to justify commenting on a question with the only truth?

The discussion about road chainrings is all very well, but rather tangential as this is a mountain bike with a chainring only 2/3 that size. MTBs used on long flat gravel stretches, or on road riding to trails, are likely to benefit from higher gears than 34/11. The OP's use of "power" is a little unfortunate (I'm a physicist so it bugs me too) but that's no reason to make unconstructive comments starting with a direct response to a new user.

And not everyone can achieve very high cadences, at least without unreasonably dedicated training. Spinning out is quite likely in this case

With microspline hubs you could get to smaller cassette sprockets, 10T onstead of 11T. But most likely you just have the wrong bike for the riding you want to do. And old fashion 2x drivetrain would have been better for you. And maybe a hybrid instead of the MTB. Or a gravel bike.

I need to change my advice. Not only are you limited in the front end by the geometry, you are limited in the back end by the 11-51 cluster. There are only two approaches:
Find a single crank that will sit with a wider chain line than the Deore. This will perform better with your high gears, and probably should work okay with the low gears although with even less efficiency. I do not know the ins and outs of moving a two piece crank laterally. This solution does allow you to keep everything else as it is with perhaps the exception of a longer chain.
The other is to completely redo your drivetrain with a double or even a triple. You cannot run this with a 11-51, so you need to decide what you need as a low gear and then work out the cassette and chainring combinations that will get you there. You must first make sure whatever crank you chose will clear the chain stay. Then you will have to add a front derailleur and shifter, change your cassette and rear derailleur. Sorry, it's pretty brutal.
Another option is to get a bike appropriate for zipping around a flat city. The bike you show is very good for its purpose - to offer a care-free trail riding adventure. But as a city bike:
those wide heavily treaded tires will slow you down more than a reasonably puncture resistant road tire.
Those heavy disk brakes might give you a little extra in the rain, provided you figure out a way to attach fenders. Otherwise, they just slow you down some more.
The over geared lows on that monstrous and heavy cassette slow you down. The under geared highs are making going fast uncomfortable and buzzy.
And let's hope no front suspension...;-)

What shifter would work with grx but in mtb style? The problem of grx shifter is that its speed bike style

If you are at the (current) top of cadans, shorter cranks may help.
Usually shorter cranks do improve how often you can get your feet round in the same time and thereby get your speed higher with the same gears.

It is hard to get short cranks for anything but the highest groupsets, though. For GRX 400 I had no choice but to get 170, no way to try 165. Edit: But now I see there is actually RX600-10 165 mm so there is some way if willing to invest.

In velomobiles we go down to 120, 155 are almost standard, and the people racing in them do have high quality requirements. I bet there will be something out there.
